# how to convert binary strings longer than 9 characters to integers?

Tags: java, binary, converters

I am working on a program where I am trying to take a binary string and convert it to an integer using this piece of code:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(count), 2);
//arrayList is a collection of 30 character binary strings
//count is an incrementing integer used to choose which string to use while inside of a while loop
```

I have tested this program with strings such as "001010", however with larger strings such as "100000110000010100001111010110" compiles, but terminal output gives me an error:

```
"@ java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:(line number))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would try using `long` or `BigInteger`

Comment: edit: tried 'long decimalValue = Long.parseLong(arrayList.get(count), 2); ' returned same error

Comment: How much longer than `9` binary digits?

Comment: in my example, my string was 30 digits binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
String bin = "100000110000010100001111010110";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bin, 2);
System.out.println(bi);
```

Output:

```
549536726
```

You can also do it using [`Long.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Long.html). However, with Long your binary strings can be up to 63 bits long, whereas with BigInteger the length can be of arbitrarily many bits.

```
String bin = "100000110000010100001111010110";
long biLong = Long.valueOf(bin, 2);
System.out.println(biLong);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Long.parseLong` method instead of `Integer.parseInt`